# multiple subdomains at apache2

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, subdomain, google-compute-engine

My webserver is Apache2 at Ubuntu 18.04.
I want to host few websites as subdomains. But after many internet advices I still doing something wrong and  my subdomains are not available. But main website are available by domain.
I created sub1.domain.com.conf file and same other.

```
<VirtualHost *:80

        ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sub1.domain.com/public_html
        ServerName sub1.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.sub1.domain.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Do I need configure **apache2.conf** some way for my purposes? Or maybe some other methods.
Thank you.
UPDATE:
*I have read some similar questions but they are not fit to my goal or environment version.
Please consider giving me an advice. I still need it yet.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the trouble was not in Apache configuration. It was correct. 
If you will have the same goal as mine, first of all you need

- create subdomains at your domain registrar
- create new A records under main domain in cloud DNS for each subdomain(Google Cloud Platform in my case)
- wait (half hour in my case)
  And only then configure Apache webserver.

Answer (score -1):

Can you show us your main domain configuration ?

I don't think it's the problem, but on this configuration you forget to close the VirtualHost tag:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
```

Comment: Thank you for responce. Tag is closed. That was copy paste mistake. My file **domain.com.conf** ```<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com
        ServerName www.domain.com
        ServerAlias domain.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>```

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Your answer is, as you stated yourself, not an actual answer to the problem. Please post such stuff as a comment under the question the next time :)